# compare date with combo box setection & delete rows between specific date range

Tags: excel, vba

[image: This is my excel sheet where I am working to get data only between a specific date range selected through two combo boxes.]

Hi there,

Thanks to you for your support I got recently. I am working with a excel sheet (image is attached here), here I have approx 60k rows repeating same date in column A. Actually what I need to do is to select start date & end date through user form (can see in image). when will click on OK button rest rows having dates out of given date range should be deleted.
but my code is not working exactly as I want & deleting some of rows which is within the range. I accept there may be my mistakes but after so many efforts I couldn't find out. And also dates in combo box is repeating so many times & not sorted. pls go thorough my codes below -

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
ComboBox2.Value = Format(ComboBox2.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub

Private Sub okButton_Click()
Dim i As Double, dt1 As String, dtt1 As String
Dim dt2 As String, dtt2 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
With ws
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
dt1 = ComboBox1.Value
dtt1 = CDate(dt1)
dt2 = ComboBox2.Value
dtt2 = CDate(dt2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lRow
If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 And Range("A" & i).Value <= dtt2 Then
     Rows(i).Select
     Selection.Delete
     i = i - 1
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
With ws
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
ComboBox1.RowSource = "A2:A" & lRow
ComboBox2.RowSource = "A2:A" & lRow
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
For i = 2 To lRow
```

try

```
For i = lRow To 2 step -1
```

Please note: I didn't check the rest of your code because probably this is the problem; when you want to delete rows (or columns) on a spreadsheet by VBA, is always a good procedure doing it from bottom to top (or right to left if you're dealing with columns).

Comment: Thank to reply I tried your suggestion but nothing is happening with this one also. I think there may be any problem with combo box or cell in column A which contains dates. when I select date from combo box somewhere date format is being changed and not matching the condition.
Request you to check the codes. OR can I send you my file?

Comment: Before you do that (I noticed another thing) declare your `dtt1` and `dtt2` as `Date`, not as `String` and try again.

Comment: Thanks my code is now working, but "AND" operator in if condition is not working.
    If Range("A" & i).Value >= dtt1 And Range("A" & i).Value <= dtt2 Then

when I try only one condition (i.e. range("A" & i) >= dtt1 then ) it works. Is there any mistake in use of "AND". or some other problem is occurring there.

Comment: It's not working because it generates a run time error? Or simply doesn't do want you want it to do?

Comment: Yes, it is not doing actually what I want it to do. sometimes it is deleting other rows or doing nothing. :-(

Comment: Ok. Maybe the problem is about the date format. I have some problems when I use a day-month-year format (the usual date format on my country) because the _standart_ format for VB is month-day-year. Just for test, try change the format to `"mm-dd-yyyy"` and run your code with some examples. If you don't see any errors then the problem is identified. Don't worry though! There are some simple things to do to correct this issue.

Comment: thanks the problem is solved now, actually there was issue with dtt declaration as I was declaring that as string & date format was change there. Thanks Pspl for you kind support. :-)